# Jacobi type identity in a general group (as an ingredient for the theorem about central extensions)

Tags: group-theory

I'm struggling with the proof of the theorem which states that the Steinberg group $St(R)$ is the central extension of the group of elementary matrices $E(R)$. This proof is given in Milnor's book about Algebraic K-theory. In the proof Milnor uses the following general fact from group theory, which he calls Jacobi identity, namely that for every group $G$ and elements $u,v,w \in G$ one has:
$$[u,[v,w]][v,[w,u]][w,[u,v]]=1 \pmod{G''} $$
where $G'=[G,G]$ is the commutator subgroup and $G''=[G',G']$. The commutator is defined as $[x,y]=xyx^{-1}y^{-1}$. He computes the following expression:
$$[uv,w][w,u][w,v][vw,u][u,v][u,w][wu,v][v,w][v,u]\tag{*}$$
He claims that $\mod{G''}$ it is the same as
$$[uv,w][wu,v][vw,u]\tag{**}$$
This last expression is just equal to $1$ by direct calculation (this is genuine equality, not only modulo $G''$). However while trying to compare $(^*)$ with $(^{**})$ I've arrived at the following expression:
$$(uwv)^{-1}wvu(vuw)^{-1}uwv(wvu)^{-1}vuw\tag{***}$$
and if everything is correct, this should belong to $G''$. However, I don't see why it is so, therefore I would to ask:

> Why expression $(^{***})$ belongs to $G''$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should have disclosed the commutators. It is easier to point out that all the commutators commute modulo $G''$, and therefore $(^*)$ equals
$$
[uv,w][wu,v][vw,u][w,u][u,w][w,v][v,w][u,v][v,u].
$$
Since $[x,y]=[y,x]^{-1}$ hence it follows.

Comment: Indeed, thank you!